# dart map<PostModel, double> sorting

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following map that represents posts and distances : `Map<PostModel, double> products = {}`
I would like to sort the map from its values, in ascending order but :

```
products.values.toList().sort();
```

doesnt work, the map remains the same. PostModel is not comparable, nor iterrable and multiple Posts can have the same distances.
So in the end, the map looks like :

```
{(post1, 100),(post2, 100),(post3, 30),(post4,450),(post5,450)....}
```

Comment: you can also consider this package: https://pub.dev/packages/sortedmap

Comment: Sortedmap doesnt work here since PostModel isn t comparable ... It can t instanciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
  final sortedValues =
      products.entries.toList()
        ..sort((key1, key2) =>
          key1.value.compareTo(key2.value)
        );
  products = Map.fromEntries(sortedValues);
  print(products);
```

Comment: works like a charm, tks, learned some very interesting methods here

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please give the answer a like (up-vote) as well if you wish.